# Denoising Autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, autoencoders

I am trying to apply DAE to my task, but since I have experienced some problem with it, to get some feeling of DAE I tried first to try to follow the study performed in http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/vincent10a/vincent10a.pdf in chapter 5.

I train my DAE having 144 inputs (12x12px) and 100 hidden layers with different strength and type of noise. The weights are tied, encoder has sigmoid non-linearity, decoder - just linear, loss fn - L2. I have ~2.5 millions images, and perform training with 5 images/minibatch. training rate is 0.05

While for Gaussian noise and Salt&Pepper i get similar results, the masking noise (which generally seems most popular) gives strange results:
[image: Learned filters after 160k, 1M, 1.9M minibatches for different noise types/levels]
(128 gray level is 0. All filters within one group have proportional color coding, ie same color means same value for all 100 filters. Black - large negative values, White - large positive)

The thing here is:

1. in the beginning/with small noise filters tend to become local blob detectors
2. for Gaussian (with big noise level, 0.5) and Salt and Pepper they then evolve into Gabor-like filters
3. For Masking noise there is a minor tendency of appearing of the Gabor like filters, but soon many of the local-blob detectors evolve to a 1-pixel detectors, suppressing the further grows of Gabor filters. Even stranger I find the fact that this happens to the bigger noise level, 0.5, which is supposed to give better generalisation.

1)What is the reason for such strange behaviour of masking noise DAE? What might I do wrong?
2)Is there a reason that with low noise (0.1, same for 0, though not shown here) I have more negative (black) local blob detectors, while with bigger (0.3) they become positive?